# I need to convert an existing date field in SQL to Month and Year and place them in a new table in two new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried this already

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (year, month, day)
SELECT 
    DATEPART(yyyy, dtProc) as year,
    DATEPART(mm, dtProc) as month,
FROM DailyHist
```

But after this insertion I need to insert more fields which then create NULL values for my recently inserted month and year fields, using this SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable(sCliNum, dtProc, sAssignNum, sCollectNum, cFees, cAdj1, cAdj2)
SELECT 
    sCliNum, 
    dtProc, 
    sAssignNum, 
    sCollectNum, 
    cFees, 
    cAdj1, 
    cAdj2 
FROM DailyHist
```

The DailyHist table layout is as follows:

```
sCliNum dtProc                  sAssignNum  sCollectNum    cFees   cAdj1       cAdj2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BADA    2011-02-01 00:00:00.000 ADJ         (Adj)          0.00    350402.30   0.00
BADA    2011-02-01 00:00:00.000 INTERE      (Adj)          0.00        43.77   0.00
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve

```
sCliNum dtProc  sAssignNum  sCollectNum cFees   cAdj1   cAdj2   year    month
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COUN    2013-07-01 00:00:00.000     IntHis  0.00    0.00    0.00    NULL    NULL    NULL     
COUN    2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 C1  FeeHis  0.00    0.00    0.00    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: For one that SQL statement won't work, please edit it. What SQL statement are you using to insert the second time around? Why are you inserting NULL's?

Comment: This is the second insert (Im not trying to insert Nulls its just removing the values from those columns.  INSERT INTO #TempTable(sCliNum, dtProc, sAssignNum, sCollectNum, cFees, cAdj1, cAdj2)
SELECT sCliNum, dtProc, sAssignNum, sCollectNum, cFees, cAdj1, cAdj2
 FROM DailyHist

Comment: Well with that statement, you are trying to insert `NULL`, because you aren't specifying a value to go into those columns. To help us understand what you need, please edit your question so we can see the layout of the table you're selecting from and the desired end-result you want to achieve.

Comment: you're adding rows to temp table without telling them where to insert them with. Add a where clause on your long list insert ie: where year = 1999 and month = 11 and day = 2. Better yet, make that two tables and relate to an added primary key/identity added to the temptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you said, this is what I think you're trying to achieve.

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable(sCliNum, dtProc, sAssignNum, sCollectNum, cFees, cAdj1, cAdj2, year, month, day)
SELECT 
    sCliNum, 
    dtProc, 
    sAssignNum, 
    sCollectNum, 
    cFees, 
    cAdj1, 
    cAdj2,
    DATEPART(yyyy, dtProc), -- year
    DATEPART(mm, dtProc),   -- month
    DATEPART(dd, dtProc)    -- day
FROM DailyHist
```